# Userform Timestamp Cell When textbox Update

Tags: excel, timestamp, userform, vba

I have a userform where I have two textboxes `txtCurrentStatus` and `txtDCPreviousStatus`.

I want the information in `txtCurrentStatus`  to display in `txtDCPreviousStatus` only if 15 days or more has passed since the last time `txtCurrentStatus` was last updated.

I have the following code:

```
Sub txtDCCurrentStatus_AfterUpdate() 
    dim oldDate as Date
    dim timeStamp as String
    dim numOfDaysSinceLastUpdated as Integer

    'currentRow is the current row that is being updated from another part of my code
    oldDate = CDate(Cells(currentRow, 219).Value)
    timestamp = "Last updated on " & oldDate & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
    numOfDaysSinceLastUpdated = DateDiff("d", oldDate, Date) 'Date is today 
    If (numOfDaysSinceLastUpdated > 15) Then
        Me.txtDCPreviousStatus.Value = timestamp & Me.txtDCPreviousStatus.Value
        Me.txtDCPreviousStatus.Value = Me.txtDCCurrentStatus.Value & _
        Chr(13) & Me.txtDCPreviousStatus.Value
        Else
            'Do nothing
    End If
    Cells(currentRow, 219).Value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
End Sub
```

I am having two issues:

1) If the `Cells(currentRow, 219).Value = ""`because `txtDCCurrentStatus` was never updated then I get a message

> Run-Time error '6': Overflow

at `numOfDaysSinceLastUpdated = DateDiff("d", oldDate, Date)`

2) To solved this issue, I moved `Cells(currentRow, 219).Value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")` at the very top. When I do that the text never move to  `txtDCPreviousStatus` because the date changes automatically to today the moment I make a change so it's never more than 15 days.

Basically, I am:

- Putting into `oldDate`, the date `txtDCCurrentStatus` was last updated
- Checking if 15 days has passed since  `txtDCCurrentStatus` was updated by doing `oldDate - Date` then putting it in `numOfDaysSinceLastUpdated`
- If yes, I then move the content of `txtDCCurrentStatus` to `txtDCPreviousStatus`
- Save now the new Date that `txtDCCurrentStatus` is being updated to `Cells(currentRow, 219).Value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")`

Is there a way I can fix these two issues?

Comment: the question is what do you want to if the text has never been updated? how to handle?

Comment: yes my question is to know how to handle the text never being updated before

Comment: if there is no `oldDate` then `txtDCPreviousStatus` should be left blank?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it is so simple that i almost feel silly hahah thank you. I added an if statement literally with your suggestion and it worked.  no more overflow error haha thank you :)

Comment: So, I guess you know how to code for that?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am posting the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ScottHoltzman answer. I fixed my issue

I added the following at the beginning of my `Sub` and it worked

```
if oldDate = Empty then 
   Me.txtDCPreviousStatus.Value = ""
Else ...
```

The issue I was having was that at first I was checking `if oldDate = ""`. Even if oldDate is empty,  `oldDate` is a `Date` and when it's empty, it print as `"12:00:00 AM"` and `"" <> "12:00:00 AM"` so I had to check if it was `empty`